# Sonata-admin filter by sub document properties

Tags: mongodb, symfony, document, sonata-admin

I use sonata admin bundle and mongodb database. I have two documents, Hotel and Room (Room EmbedOne Hotel) and I want to filter the rooms according to the names of hotels.

This is possible if we work with entities:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters (DatagridMapper $ datagrid)
     {
         $ datagrid
             -> add ('hotel.name')
         ;
     }
```

What is the syntax when using documents related with mongodb database?

Thank you.